What inflates the size of an input?
I have an issue with an input exploding outside its intended boundaries. The problem looks like following:

The relevant part of raw HTML looks like following (first along with full CSS):
<td class="relative whitespace-nowrap pl-3 first:pl-4 sm:first:pl-6 pr-3 last:pr-4 sm:last:pr-6 text-main-900 dark:text-main-50 text-left border-b border-main-200 dark:border-main-800 py-2.5">
  <div class="max-w-20">
    <div class="flex flex-row">
      <div data-slot="control" class="flex flex-row grow shadow mr-1">
        <div class="min-w-8 flex flex-row justify-center items-center border-l border-t border-b text-xs text-main-text bg-main-static-bg border-main-border/20 dark:text-main-text-dark dark:bg-main-static-bg-dark dark:border-main-border-dark/10 rounded-l-lg">
          <span data-slot="control" class="group inline-flex focus:outline-none" id="headlessui-checkbox-:r9v:" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" tabindex="0" data-headlessui-state="">
            <span class="relative isolate flex size-[1.125rem] items-center justify-center rounded-[0.3125rem] sm:size-4 before:absolute before:inset-0 before:-z-10 before:rounded-[calc(0.3125rem-1px)] before:bg-white before:shadow before:group-data-[checked]:bg-[--checkbox-checked-bg] dark:before:hidden dark:bg-white/5 dark:group-data-[checked]:bg-[--checkbox-checked-bg] border border-zinc-950/15 group-data-[checked]:border-transparent group-data-[checked]:group-data-[hover]:border-transparent group-data-[hover]:border-zinc-950/30 group-data-[checked]:bg-[--checkbox-checked-border] dark:border-white/15 dark:group-data-[checked]:border-white/5 dark:group-data-[checked]:group-data-[hover]:border-white/5 dark:group-data-[hover]:border-white/30 after:absolute after:inset-0 after:rounded-[calc(0.3125rem-1px)] after:shadow-[inset_0_1px_theme(colors.white/15%)] dark:after:-inset-px dark:after:hidden dark:after:rounded-[0.3125rem] dark:group-data-[checked]:after:block group-data-[focus]:outline group-data-[focus]:outline-2 group-data-[focus]:outline-offset-2 group-data-[focus]:outline-blue-500 group-data-[disabled]:opacity-50 group-data-[disabled]:border-zinc-950/25 group-data-[disabled]:bg-zinc-950/5 group-data-[disabled]:[--checkbox-check:theme(colors.zinc.950/50%)] group-data-[disabled]:before:bg-transparent dark:group-data-[disabled]:border-white/20 dark:group-data-[disabled]:bg-white/[2.5%] dark:group-data-[disabled]:[--checkbox-check:theme(colors.white/50%)] dark:group-data-[disabled]:group-data-[checked]:after:hidden forced-colors:[--checkbox-check:HighlightText] forced-colors:[--checkbox-checked-bg:Highlight] forced-colors:group-data-[disabled]:[--checkbox-check:Highlight] dark:forced-colors:[--checkbox-check:HighlightText] dark:forced-colors:[--checkbox-checked-bg:Highlight] dark:forced-colors:group-data-[disabled]:[--checkbox-check:Highlight] [--checkbox-check:theme(colors.white)] [--checkbox-checked-bg:theme(colors.zinc.900)] [--checkbox-checked-border:theme(colors.zinc.950/90%)] dark:[--checkbox-checked-bg:theme(colors.zinc.600)]">
              <svg class="size-4 stroke-[--checkbox-check] opacity-0 group-data-[checked]:opacity-100 sm:h-3.5 sm:w-3.5" viewBox="0 0 14 14" fill="none">
                (...)
              </svg>
            </span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <input class="relative block grow appearance-none px-[calc(theme(spacing[3.5])-1px)] py-[calc(theme(spacing[2.5])-1px)] sm:px-[calc(theme(spacing[3])-1px)] sm:py-[calc(theme(spacing[1.5])-1px)] text-base/6 text-main-text placeholder:text-main-text/50 dark:placeholder:text-main-text-dark/30 sm:text-sm/6 dark:text-main-text-dark border border-main-border/20 data-[hover]:border-main-border-hover/30 dark:border-main-border-dark/10 dark:data-[hover]:border-main-border-dark-hover/20 bg-white dark:bg-white/5 focus:outline-none focus:border-b-2 focus:border-b-primary-500 focus:hover:border-b-primary-500 focus:pb-[calc(theme(spacing[2.5])-2px)] sm:focus:pb-[calc(theme(spacing[1.5])-2px)] data-[invalid]:border-danger-500 data-[invalid]:data-[hover]:border-danger-500 data-[invalid]:dark:border-danger-500 data-[invalid]:data-[hover]:dark:border-danger-500 data-[invalid]:focus:border-b-primary-500 data-[invalid]:data-[hover]:focus:border-b-primary-500 data-[disabled]:opacity-50 data-[disabled]:border-main-border/20 dark:data-[hover]:data-[disabled]:border-white/15 dark:data-[disabled]:border-main-border-dark/15 dark:data-[disabled]:bg-main-50/[2.5%] dark:[color-scheme:dark] rounded-l-none rounded-r-lg" id="headlessui-input-:ra1:" data-headlessui-state="" value="">
      </div>
      <button class="relative isolate inline-flex items-center justify-center gap-x-2 rounded-lg border text-base/6 font-semibold px-[calc(theme(spacing[3.5])-1px)] py-[calc(theme(spacing[2.5])-1px)] sm:px-[calc(theme(spacing.3)-1px)] sm:py-[calc(theme(spacing[1.5])-1px)] sm:text-sm/6 focus:outline-none data-[focus]:outline data-[focus]:outline-2 data-[focus]:outline-offset-2 data-[focus]:outline-primary-500 data-[disabled]:opacity-50 [&>[data-slot=icon]]:-mx-0.5 [&>[data-slot=icon]]:my-0.5 [&>[data-slot=icon]]:size-5 [&>[data-slot=icon]]:shrink-0 [&>[data-slot=icon]]:text-[--btn-icon] [&>[data-slot=icon]]:sm:my-1 [&>[data-slot=icon]]:sm:size-4 forced-colors:[--btn-icon:ButtonText] forced-colors:data-[hover]:[--btn-icon:ButtonText] border-transparent text-main-900 data-[hover]:data-[active]:bg-main-700/[10%] data-[hover]:bg-main-700/[2.5%] dark:text-main-50 dark:data-[hover]:dark:data-[active]:bg-main-300/40 dark:data-[hover]:bg-main-300/10 data-[hover]:data-[active]:[--btn-icon:theme(colors.main.400)] data-[hover]:[--btn-icon:theme(colors.main.700)] dark:data-[active]:[--btn-icon:theme(colors.main.400)] dark:data-[hover]:[--btn-icon:theme(colors.main.400)] [--btn-icon:theme(colors.main.500)] cursor-default" type="button" data-headlessui-state="">
        <span class="-translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 absolute left-1/2 top-1/2 size-[max(100%,2.75rem)] [@media(pointer:fine)]:hidden" aria-hidden="true">
        </span>
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true" data-slot="icon">
            (...)
          </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>

I'm using tailwind CSS, so this is virtually the whole CSS - there are no additional styles used apart from these above.
Below the same code stripped to only those classes which influences sizes:
<td class="relative whitespace-nowrap pl-3 first:pl-4 sm:first:pl-6 pr-3 last:pr-4 sm:last:pr-6 py-2.5">
  <div class="max-w-20">                      <!-- Split from the below for testing purposes -->
    <div class="flex flex-row">               <!-- Contents of the cell: input and button -->
      <div class="flex flex-row grow mr-1">   <!-- Host div for the input -->
        <div class="min-w-8 flex flex-row justify-center items-center"> <!-- Area with checkbox -->
          <span class="group inline-flex">                              <!-- Checkbox -->
            <span class="relative isolate flex size-[1.125rem] items-center justify-center sm:size-4">
              <svg class="size-4 sm:h-3.5 sm:w-3.5" viewBox="0 0 14 14" fill="none">
                (...)
              </svg>
            </span>
          </span>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Input part of the high-level input -->

        <input class="relative block grow appearance-none px-[calc(theme(spacing[3.5])-1px)] py-[calc(theme(spacing[2.5])-1px)] sm:px-[calc(theme(spacing[3])-1px)] sm:py-[calc(theme(spacing[1.5])-1px)] focus:pb-[calc(theme(spacing[2.5])-2px)] sm:focus:pb-[calc(theme(spacing[1.5])-2px)]">
      </div>

      <!-- The last button in the cell -->

      <button class="relative isolate inline-flex items-center justify-center gap-x-2 px-[calc(theme(spacing[3.5])-1px)] py-[calc(theme(spacing[2.5])-1px)] sm:px-[calc(theme(spacing.3)-1px)] sm:py-[calc(theme(spacing[1.5])-1px)] [&>[data-slot=icon]]:-mx-0.5 [&>[data-slot=icon]]:my-0.5 [&>[data-slot=icon]]:size-5 [&>[data-slot=icon]]:sm:my-1 [&>[data-slot=icon]]:sm:size-4">
        <span class="-translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 absolute left-1/2 top-1/2 size-[max(100%,2.75rem)] [@media(pointer:fine)]:hidden" aria-hidden="true">
        </span>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true" data-slot="icon">
          (...)
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>

And a reproducible example - nothing is shown because of lack of color classes, but you can inspect the layout and see the input overflowing.


<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>

<td class="relative whitespace-nowrap pl-3 first:pl-4 sm:first:pl-6 pr-3 last:pr-4 sm:last:pr-6 py-2.5">
  <div class="max-w-20">
    <div class="flex flex-row">
      <div class="flex flex-row mr-1">
        <div class="min-w-8 flex flex-row justify-center items-center">
          <span class="group inline-flex">
            <span class="relative isolate flex size-[1.125rem] items-center justify-center sm:size-4">
              <svg class="size-4 sm:h-3.5 sm:w-3.5" viewBox="0 0 14 14" fill="none">
                (...)
              </svg>
            </span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <input class="relative block grow appearance-none px-[calc(theme(spacing[3.5])-1px)] py-[calc(theme(spacing[2.5])-1px)] sm:px-[calc(theme(spacing[3])-1px)] sm:py-[calc(theme(spacing[1.5])-1px)] focus:pb-[calc(theme(spacing[2.5])-2px)] sm:focus:pb-[calc(theme(spacing[1.5])-2px)]">
      </div>
      <button class="relative isolate inline-flex items-center justify-center gap-x-2 px-[calc(theme(spacing[3.5])-1px)] py-[calc(theme(spacing[2.5])-1px)] sm:px-[calc(theme(spacing.3)-1px)] sm:py-[calc(theme(spacing[1.5])-1px)] [&>[data-slot=icon]]:-mx-0.5 [&>[data-slot=icon]]:my-0.5 [&>[data-slot=icon]]:size-5 [&>[data-slot=icon]]:sm:my-1 [&>[data-slot=icon]]:sm:size-4">
        <span class="-translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 absolute left-1/2 top-1/2 size-[max(100%,2.75rem)] [@media(pointer:fine)]:hidden" aria-hidden="true">
        </span>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true" data-slot="icon">
          (...)
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>



The w-20 is added for debugging purposes - it was supposed to forcefully shrink the input element, but it didn't. Chrome shows information for the "w-20" div:

Input's width seems to be unbound by CSS anyhow - it has to derive it from parent containers:

Going outwards, input's parent (input host div) width:

Cell content div's width:

Also shown BTW that its content exceed its size:

My requirement for the input is to shrink to the size of its host div, so that I can control width of the whole input component (along with prefix box and postfix box, which is not used in this case).
My questions: Why doesn't input shrink, but instead overflows its container? What actually influences the width of the input?

you're probably using a fixed unit rather than a relative one for the width

@Pete, which specific width are you referring to?

The width of the input - not sure what your classes do but it looks like you are using specific px widths for your breakpoints

The minimum width of a flexbox item defaults to min-content. Therefore, the <input> will not shrink below its intrinsic size.
Here's a simplified example:


<div style="border: 1px dotted red; max-width:7em;padding:1px;">
  <div style="display:flex;border:1px dotted blue;padding:1px;">
      <div style="display:flex;justify-content:center;min-width:2rem;">
        <input type="checkbox"/>
      </div>
      <input style="flex:1 1 auto;background:rgb(255 0 0 / .4);" placeholder="Foo" />
  </div>
</div>




Changing the <input>'s min-width to 0 allows it to shrink to fit:


<div style="border: 1px dotted red; max-width:7em;padding:1px;">
  <div style="display:flex;border:1px dotted blue;padding:1px;">
      <div style="display:flex;justify-content:center;min-width:2rem;">
        <input type="checkbox"/>
      </div>
      <input style="flex:1 1 auto;min-width:0;background:rgb(255 0 0 / .4);" placeholder="Foo" />
  </div>
</div>




Updating your example:

Add min-w-0 to <div class="flex flex-row mr-1">
Add min-w-0 to <input ...>



<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>

<td class="relative whitespace-nowrap pl-3 first:pl-4 sm:first:pl-6 pr-3 last:pr-4 sm:last:pr-6 py-2.5">
  <div class="max-w-20 p-1" style="background:rgb(0 0 0 / 0.2);">
    <div class="flex flex-row">
      <div class="min-w-0 flex flex-row mr-1">
        <div class="min-w-8 flex flex-row justify-center items-center">
          <span class="group inline-flex">
            <span class="relative isolate flex size-[1.125rem] items-center justify-center sm:size-4">
              <svg class="size-4 sm:h-3.5 sm:w-3.5" viewBox="0 0 14 14" fill="none">
                (...)
              </svg>
            </span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <input class="min-w-0 relative block grow appearance-none px-[calc(theme(spacing[3.5])-1px)] py-[calc(theme(spacing[2.5])-1px)] sm:px-[calc(theme(spacing[3])-1px)] sm:py-[calc(theme(spacing[1.5])-1px)] focus:pb-[calc(theme(spacing[2.5])-2px)] sm:focus:pb-[calc(theme(spacing[1.5])-2px)]" style="border:1px solid blue;" placeholder="Foo">
      </div>
      <button class="relative isolate inline-flex items-center justify-center gap-x-2 px-[calc(theme(spacing[3.5])-1px)] py-[calc(theme(spacing[2.5])-1px)] sm:px-[calc(theme(spacing.3)-1px)] sm:py-[calc(theme(spacing[1.5])-1px)] [&>[data-slot=icon]]:-mx-0.5 [&>[data-slot=icon]]:my-0.5 [&>[data-slot=icon]]:size-5 [&>[data-slot=icon]]:sm:my-1 [&>[data-slot=icon]]:sm:size-4">
        <span class="-translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 absolute left-1/2 top-1/2 size-[max(100%,2.75rem)] [@media(pointer:fine)]:hidden" aria-hidden="true">
        </span>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true" data-slot="icon">
          (...)
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>



